# $L_p$ norm $\leq L_2$ norm for $1\leq p\leq2$ for Random Variables

Tags: probability, normed-spaces, expectation, lp-spaces

Let {$X_i;i\geq0$} be a sequence of random variables defined on the probability space ($\Omega,\mathcal{F},P$). If $||.||_p$ is the $L^p$ norm defined as $||X_i||_p=(E[|X_i|^p])^{1/p}$, how should I prove that $||X_i||_p\leq||X_i||_2$ for $1\leq p\leq2$?

Does it follow from Jensen's inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. It follows from Jensen's inequality. By Jensen's inequality, if $Z$ is a random variable and $\varphi$ is a convex function, then
$$
\varphi\left(\operatorname EZ\right) \le \operatorname E\varphi(Z).
$$
Let $\varphi(x)=x^{2/p}$ with $p\le 2$ and $Z=|X|^p$. Then
$$
(E|X|^p)^{2/p}\le E|X|^2.
$$
Taking the square root of each side gives the result.

Alternatively, the same inequality can be obtained using [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Probability_measure).

Comment: That's great! Thanks for your help

Comment: @user120768 You're welcome!